# How do I programmatically set class level permissions in Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

According to the [Parse Schema Javascript docs](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.3.2/Parse.Schema.html#.all), there does not seem to be a way to set classLevelPermission using the JS api. It seems to be possible via the [REST api](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#modifying-the-schema), however. Is there a way to do it with the JS api?

Answer (score 1):

try this in javascript.This is for your reference i did this in angular 6 -

```
setCLP() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': enter application id ,
        'X-Parse-Master-Key': enter master key

      })
    };

   {
        "url": 'your schema url' + 'enter your classname ',

        "reqparam":{

          "className" : abc,

          "classLevelPermissions" :
          {
            "find": {

                '*' : true
            },

              '*' : true
            },
            "create": { '*': true },
            "update": { '*': false },
            "delete": { '*' : true },
          }
        } 
      }, httpOptions).toPromise();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for setting CLP with the JavaScript SDK, hopefully this is a feature we will see added in the future.

See [this issue](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/583) for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is now [available in the Parse JS SDK](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Schema.html#setCLP).

> setCLP(clp) → {Parse.Schema}
>
> Sets Class Level Permissions when creating / updating a Schema.